# Thread sleeps longer then expected

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
    let k = time::Instant::now();
    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_micros(10));
    let elapsed = k.elapsed().as_micros();
    println!("{}", elapsed);
```

My output is always somewhere between 70 and 90. I expect it to be 10, why is this number 7x higher?

Comment: Thread sleeps are not guaranteed to be the exact same time.

Comment: The typical OS scheduler tick rates are like 50 ms, so unless you're using a real time OS, you won't be able to get this kind of granularity

Comment: @Alexander i am doing some IoT stuff and need exact measurments. Whats the best way to achive it in rust could you provide me some documentations?

Comment: What "IoT" stuff are you doing? Sounds like an XY problem. There's no way you can get that kind of accuracy on a non-realtime OS.

Comment: @bill.gates It's not really about Rust. Any process on your system will be preempted at indeterminate times (typically *at least* once every 50 ms), and what you do or what language you use in this process simply doesn't matter. You have some options, though. 1. You can find a way to pin your thread to a core, if that's a thing your OS supports. 2. You can offload your computation onto some subsystem that's optimized for the concrete task you're looking to achieve (you haven't told use yet), e.g. using a soundcard to generate a sine wave, or 3. switch to an RTOS

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo i am reading if an sensor is high or low. Like in this example: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Proximity/HCSR04.pdf at the bottom i need to trigger the sensor with 10 micro seconds, and then i need the difference between the trigger and the incoming echo. My application does not work as expected and i try to figure out the problem and i found out that the sleep isnt accurate

Comment: @Alexander if that's the case, it seems to me that when a computer runs at 4 gHz, it's running 4e+9 operations per second. It would seem that then a computer is running one operation every 0.0000000003 seconds, or one every 0.0000003 ms. Am I misinterpreting units here, is this misleading marketing on the parts of companies, or am I failing to account for something else? Also, you should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: @2br-2b What you said is correct, but only for a particular definition of "operation", which is: a CPU tick, during which one or more CPU instructions can be performed. There's not a 1:1 between a rust expression and a CPU tick (*not even close*), and again, there's in the OS in the way, doing its job to share the CPU between you and the other processes of the system

Comment: Yeah no. A normal windows/linux usermode process is not going to be precise enough to grab data off that sensor. You either need a specialized OS or a microcontroller sitting in front of the ultrasound sensor. In any case, this question is definitely an XY problem.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo well i use an raspberry PI. I guess i have to use things like HAL https://github.com/rp-rs/rp-hal/tree/main/rp2040-hal

Comment: @bill.gates Is connecting your RPi to a cheap micro controller over I2C or SPI an option? It'd prob be the easiest way if i had to guess

Comment: @Alexander well i have an raspberry pi WH and raspberry pi b3+. Buying an additional micro controller is currently not an option. I know i could make the code work with python because they are alot of premade libraries but i want it to make it run on rust. I mean its the same device just different language there must be an way

Comment: @bill.gates " Buying an additional micro controller is currently not an option." Fair enough! You should investigate the other options like thread pinning, offloading to the hardware, or switching to an RTOS. "I know i could make the code work with python". You couldn't. Please re-read my earlier comment: Rust is a complete red herring, and not the source of your problem.

Comment: @Alexander alright. Thank you for your guidance, i will read more about it and how it works!

Comment: @bill.gates Since you're on a Raspberry Pi, I bet you're running some kind of linux or another. Linux supports thread pinning, and so does your hardware (it's multi-core), and it's probably your easiest bet (your existing software will run as-is). On the downside, your core gets fully used up (d'uh), which will lower your throughput for other things (which may or may not be an issue for you, depending on what else you're trying to do at the same time on the one RPi). I'll cook up my comments into a comment.

Comment: @Alexander yes, i use linux. Linux lite, no desktop just an console and control it over SSH. I am pretty new to rust and i have this PI and a bunch of sensor wich i want to try out. Letting a LED blink feeled lame and was done in like 1 min.

Comment: If your CPU is very busy, the only way this can be done is with a realtime OS. However in practice you can probably get away with a simple busy loop: `while k.elapsed() < Duration::from_micros(10) {}`.

Comment: You might also be able to get better results by setting your thread to real-time but AFAIK Rust doesn't expose the corresponding API, so you will need an unsafe FFI call to [`pthread_setschedparam`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually doesn't really have anything to do with Rust.

On a typical multi-processing, user-interactive operating system (i.e., every consumer OS you've used), your thread isn't special. It's one among many, and the CPUs need to be shared.

You operating system has a component called a scheduler, whose job it is to share the hardware resources. It will boot off your thread off the CPU quite often. This typically happens:

1. On every system call
2. Every time an interrupt hits the CPU
3. When the scheduler kicks you off to give other processes/threads a chance (this is called preemption, and typically happens 10s of times a second)

Thus, your userland process can't possibly do anything timing-related with such fine precision.

There's several solution paths you can explore:

1. Increase the amount of CPU your operating system gives you. Some ideas:

   - Increase the process' priortiy
   - Pin the thread to a particular CPU core, to give it exclusive use (this means you lose throughput, because if your thread is idle, no other thread's work can borrow that CPU)
2. Switch to a [real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) which makes guarantees about latency and timing.
3. Offload the work to some hardware that's specialized for it, without the involvement of your process.

   - E.g. offload sine wave generation to a hardware sound-card, WiFi radio processing to a WiFi controller, etc.
   - Use your own micro controller to do the real-time stuff, and communicate to it over something like I2C or SPI.

In your case of running some simple code on a userland process, I think your easiest bet is to just pin your process. Your existing code will work as-is, you'll just lose the throughput of one of your cores (but luckily, you have multiple).